# Rebol PARSE rule to match thru first occurrence of at least 2 spaces

Tags: parsing, rebol, red

`rule: [while [not ["--"] skip] some "-"]
parse "a-bc----d" [rule ??]`

prints

`??: "d"`

But I need a more efficient rule (e.g. using `to #"-"`)...

EDIT:

`t: copy "" append/dup t "." 10000 append t "-..---..--"
rule: [while [not ["--"] skip] some "-"]
print [delta-time [loop 1000 [parse t [rule] ]]]`

=> ~ 15.4 sec on my phone

`rule: [any ["--" break | skip] any "-"]`

=> ~ 8.2 sec

`rule: [to "--" some "-"]` (@sqlab response)

=> ~ 0.3 sec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What prevents you to use *to* as e.g.

```
rule: [to "--" some "-"  x:]
```

Comment: Sqlab, if you have some time, please check [that similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54577826/rebol-parse-rule-to-match-to-first-occurrence-of-at-least-2-blanks)