# Rebol PARSE rule to match to first occurrence of at least 2 #[none]s

Tags: parsing, rebol

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560201/rebol-parse-rule-to-match-thru-first-occurrence-of-at-least-2-spaces/54568754#54568754) for string case.

In R3-Alpha, I tried to adapt the @sqlab response to block case:

```
parse [x x x x #[none] a #[none] #[none] b] [to [none! none!] ??]
```

I expect `??: [#[none] #[none] b]`, but get

```
** Script error: PARSE - invalid rule or usage of rule: none!
```

It's the result right and my expectation wrong?  Or it's a bug?

Comment: And downvote is because... ?

Comment: The implementation of TO and THRU in R3-Alpha parse is very incomplete, and there are some big questions about what it should do.  Red supports it, but if you say **parse "abaab" [to [(print <x>) "aab"]]** for instance, that will print `<x>` three times.  "Optimizations" in R3-Alpha would appear to have been trying to avoid the overhead this represents...but they may well have not been very good optimizations.  You should look at the source and see what *you* think!

Comment: Thank you for editing the question... Fact is, I can't test things in R2, R3 or Red on Android, nor I can post questions tagged 'ren-c'. So probably SO is out for me, about Rebol questions :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can just show a solution for Red and Rebol2. As the words in the rule are reduced automatic, you have to shield them.

Red

```
>> parse [x x x x _ a _ _ b] [to [ '_ '_] y: ]
== false
>> 
>> y
== [_ _ b]
```

Rebol2

```
>> parse [x x x x _ a _ _ b] [some [r: [ '_ '_  ] (y: r) | skip]   ]
== true
>> y
== [_ _ b]
```

After the editing of the question by *HostileFork* the solution for Red looks like that

```
>> parse [x x x x #[none] a #[none] #[none] b] [to [none! none!] y:] 
== false
>> y
== [none none b]
>>
```

example according the question in the comment of *giuliolunati*

```
>> parse  [x x x x 0 a 1 2 b]  [to [integer! integer!] y:]
== false
>> y
== [1 2 b]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but he was trying to ask a different question (where _ is a notation for #[none]).  *(While it's generally not good to edit questions in a way that invalidates answers, this is a misunderstanding case... so probably worthy of an exception.)*

Comment: The title says **2 BLANKS**

Comment: Thank you, I should have posted the question with different example, say "first 2 consecutive integers in [x x x x 0 a 1 2 b]" ... then in Red `[to [integer! integer!] y:]` should work?